# What are potential issues with the following code? short foo() { short a,b,c; b=10; c = a + b; return c; }

Tags: c, type-conversion, initialization, arguments

What are potential issues with the following code?

```
short foo()
{
    short a,b,c;
    b=10;

   c = a + b;

   return c; 
 }
```

Comment: a Is not defined! Here it begins

Comment: Use of uninitialized `a` is cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: What if the function signature is changed to
short foo(short a) and a is removed as a stack variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable a was not initialized. It has an indeterminate value.

Comment: There is a point for closing: `Questions seeking debugging help` You are free to use it