# Compiler error in C code that I cannot understand

Tags: c, debugging

I wrote this code:

```
short foo(short a)
{
short b,c;
b=10;

c = a + b;

return c; 
}
```

I am getting a compiler error as :

```
usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':                                                                                                                        
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'                                                                                                                                                                   
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could where I am going wrong?

Does a remain indeterminate here?  I am little new to C programming and so please excuse my ignorance of a few obvious things.

Comment: I assume that you meant to compile with the `-c` option, and that `main` is in another file.

Comment: You have multiple accounts to ask same question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729505

Comment: I need an answer quickly and I wasnt being allowed to ask again. 
I am new here and I wasnt able to figure out wat to do. my previous Question went into hold and I dont know how to remove it. I deleted the previous question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a compiler error but a linker error. The code you showed is not broken, it is incomplete. The message

```
undefined reference to `main'
```

tells you that you have not defined a `main` function, which is needed as the starting point of the program. Add

```
int main(void) {
  // code here that is supposed to run when the program is executed
}
```

to the code.

Comment: Could you give me tje difference of when I define 'a' as a stack variable and change it to short foo(short a) to short foo()?? 

What is the difference between the two initializations??

Comment: `a` in `short foo(short a)` is a function parameter, so that calling `foo(10)` will enter `foo` with `a` set to `10`. If you declare `foo` as `short foo()`, it will be callable as `foo()` instead (without a parameter), and if you declare `a` locally in `foo`, it will have whatever value you give it there (or an unspecified one, if you don't give it one). But what does that have to do with your question about the linker error?

Comment: I was trying to compare thee two codes by running both separately to understand how they were being compiled.